# Passing a pointer by reference?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [passing a pointer by reference in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9231483/passing-a-pointer-by-reference-in-c)

I have a function that needs to modify a pointer, ex:

```
bool someFunc(Something* something)
{
   something = somethingElse;
   return true;
}
```

The pointer is passed by value through and is not modified. How can I modify it?

Thanks

Comment: Your question title implies you already know the answer...

Comment: Your reputation implies that you *should* already know the answer. Or at least the means to find out.

Comment: Nope, I have never had a pointer reference in C++.

Comment: But wouldn't it be logical to try like you would any other reference? Also, you could work backwards and fit in into code: a reference `&` to a pointer `*` to Something `Something`. Remembering that these things go right to left, the expression becomes `Something * &`.

Comment: @chris I have a phobia of compiler errors.

Comment: @ChrisA. That reputation is almost entirely from questions, not answers.  An amazing feat if you ask me.

Comment: @ChrisA. Reputation across the site does not imply knowledge of a particular. I have a much higher reputation than Milo, and yet know nothing of say... lisp, F, R, visualbasic...

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas but you certainly have the means to find out something so simple.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just change the function signature to look like

```
bool someFunc(Something* &something)
```

and you'll get a modifiable pointer in `someFunc()`.

Answer (score 3):

```
bool someFunc(Something * &something)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
bool someFunc ( Something * & something ); 
                         // ^ notice the reference symbol
```